# How to live stream AW Zombies

Tags: ps3, streaming, call-of-duty-advanced-warfare

I would like to be able to live stream AW Zombies to YouTube, but I don't know how. I don't have enough money to buy a recording device. I have contacted both other players and YouTube and they haven't responded. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 5):

Before you can stream your gameplay, you need to be able to record it. Unfortunately, the PS3 does not have recording functionality, so a screen capturing device is a necessity, even if you don't want to buy one.

By far a simpler and better alternative, would be to buy a PS4 instead. It is not only capable of recording everything it can display, but it also offers a "stream to YouTube" feature. In addition to that, it is more future-proof than the PS3 (future games are more likely to be released on PS4 than PS3) and Advanced Warfare has already been released to the PS4.

Regardless of which option you choose, you'll have to spend money for *something*.